# Why do "prisoner" and "jailer" mean different things?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nouns

If *jail* and *prison* are (at least nearly) synonymous, why does *jailer* refer to the captor, and *prisoner* refer to the captive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer would be that *jail* may be used as a verb, but *prison* is verbed only in archaic poetry (*imprison* takes its place in ordinary modern speech). People may be *jailed*, but who ever says they are *prisoned*?

Comment: That makes about halfway sense to me.  But still - why then is "prisoner" a word at all?

Comment: "jailer" is referring to 'a person who jails'. Jail is being used as verb. "prisoner" is 'a person who belongs to prison'. Prison is noun here.

Comment: @Danielδ - Other examples: pensioner (one who receives a pension), commoner (one who belongs to the commons)... probably a bunch of others, but my brain just ran dry.

Comment: I see.  So [noun]-er is someone who makes use of the [noun], and [verb]-er is someone who [verb]s.  Makes complete sense to me now.  It's just that it wasn't obvious that *jail* is a verb, especially when set side-by-side with *prison*.

Comment: A [noun/adjective/adverb]-er isn’t necessarily someone who _makes use_ of [N/A/A]—it’s rather more vague than that. It’s just someone who is somehow or other _associated_ with [N/A/A]. A foreigner, for instance, does not ‘use’ foreign lands, he is just generically associated with ‘foreign’. These words can be considered a type of determinative compounds, with the _-er_ suffix functioning as the compound head.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like the distinction in meaning between *prisoner* and *jailer* was already present in the French ancestors of these words.
The word *prisoner* in the sense of "occupant of a prison" seems to be derived from the French and Old French word *prisoner/prisonnier.*

The noun and adjective suffix -*(i)ier* in French (derived from Latin *-arius*) seems to be used somewhat differently from the suffix *-er* in English. While English *-er* nouns mostly refer to agents of a corresponding verb, French *-ier* words often seem to be based on nouns, and refer to someone whose profession or location is related to that noun. For example, the French word *[caissier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caissier)* (the source of modern English "cashier") is derived from the noun *caisse* "box/cash register", not from a verb. It doesn't mean "a person who cashes", it means something like "the person associated with/located at the box (where money is kept)".

The [Wiktionary entry on *-ier* in Old French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ier#Old_French) says that one of its uses was to form nouns that "[indicate] location, where one lives". So I think *prisoner* can be explained as referring to "a person who is located in/lives in a prison".

The word *[jailer/jailor/gaoler](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jailer),* in contrast, seems to have had some influence (as the *-or* spelling variant implies) from a French word with the French agent-marking suffix *-eur* (derived from Latin *-or*). Now, I don't think this is necessarily very explanatory, since it seems the forms with *-eur* showed variation with forms in *-ier* in French. (In fact, the form used in Modern French has *-ier*: *[geôlier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ge%C3%B4lier)*). But I think it may play a small part in the explanation for why *jailer* didn't develop the meaning of *prisoner*. Despite the apparent similarity in form between these words, their etymological sources are not entirely the same. (The other part of the explanation may simply be that *-ier* in French has a broad enough meaning, or at least did at the time these words were formed, to encompass both of these meanings.)

Once these words had entered English, the (apparently pre-existing in French) distinction between their meanings would likely have been reinforced by the fact that, as Robusto observes, *jail* is more commonly used as a verb than *prison.*

According to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), there are (seemingly rare) examples in Middle English of the word *prisoner* being used to mean *jailer/jailor/gaoler*:

> - a1325  (▸c1250)    *Gen. & Exod.* (1968) l. 2042   An litel stund quile he [*sc.* Joseph] was ðer, So gan him luuen ðe prisuner.
> - c1450  (▸c1405)    *Mum & Sothsegger* (BL Add. 41666) (1936) 1251 (*MED*)   Pouerte hath a pressonere whenne he doeth passe bondes.

Comment: Related: [What is a carpenter if he doesn't carpent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33151)