# What is a carpenter if he doesn't carpent?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, morphology

Why does "carpenter" end in "er" if "carpent" isn't a word?  Same with "butcher". (As in: "I butch for a living.")

Comment: Consider that the verbs are "to butcher" and "to carpenter", and "a butcherer" and "a carpenterer" would sound silly. (This reasoning is entirely false, since the nouns were in existence literally centuries before the verbs - but it might help you feel better about the whole situation :-)

Comment: Possibly a very short answer is "because it comes from the French".

Comment: You meant 'if "carpent" isn't a VERB', I presume.

Comment: I imagine he's a carpeter with an extra n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of their etymology.

> ORIGIN Middle English: from
>   Anglo-Norman French, from Old French
>   carpentier, charpentier, from late
>   Latin carpentarius (artifex) ‘carriage
>   (maker),’ from carpentum ‘wagon,’ of
>   Gaulish origin; related to car.
>
> ORIGIN Middle English: from an
>   Anglo-Norman French variant of Old
>   French bochier, from boc ‘he-goat,’
>   probably of the same ultimate origin
>   as buck.
>
> (OED)

Comment: Harrold: Any relation to Mark?